# Bing Map REST API Json not getting data, tried everything I could

Tags: json, rest, dictionary, bing-maps, bing

```js
var url = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=" 
+ encodeURIComponent('Oakleaf Dr Meadow Valley CA 95956 United States')
+ "&incl=queryParse"
+ "&output=json"
+ "&key=" + key
$.ajax({
 url:url,
 type:"GET",
 dataType:"jason",
 success: function(data){
  lat=data.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates[0];
 },
 error: function(r){ console.log(r)}
 });
```

I get error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=Oakleaf%20Dr%20Meadow%…=json&key=... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

OK, I searched for answers, must use jsonp.

```
$.ajax({
url: url,
  type: "GET",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: "jsonp",
  success: function(data) {
var lat=data.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates[0],
lng=data.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates[1];
    console.log(lat);
  },
  error: function(response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
  }
});
```

Then, I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"
The answer most I found was to make changes to server side script, which is not applicable in this case. Now what?

Comment: did the syntax error throw by error function ?  error: function(response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
  }
or during the request

Answer (score 0):

Well, Im sure of that syntax Error is coming from error function

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
```

this will not work unless if the response has a **JSON header**, so basically if this request reached the server and server gave you an error then you have to add a header to the response at server side otherwise you can replace it by

```
console.log(response);
```

in this way ,it will write an object to console